# Video plays on iOS but gives android videoview error 1, -2147483648

Tags: android, ios, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

So I have an Android and iOS version of my app. The main task that this app does is play video from my cloud storage. Both versions use the exact same URLs and videos. I originally hosted my videos on Google Cloud Storage, and both versions were able to play the videos. I recently transferred all the videos to an Azure Blob but now only the iOS version is able to play the videos. The android version gives me an "android videoview error 1, -2147483648". Most of the solutions I found have to do with either accessing local files or issues with the videos being hosted on a server. But since the video files are the exact same, and the only thing that changes is the host, I'm assuming it has something to do with how Android interacts with the Azure Blob. What is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you for palying videos over internet use third library to handle it.

Exoplayer is a third party library for that which is developed by Google, for faster usage i advise you use ExoMedia(its is developed over Exoplayer and usage is simpler than Exo)

here is the link:
[ExoMedia library for android](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia)